# Phonejs toolbar menu text shows twice

Tags: javascript, html, phonejs

Recently, I use the Html5 framework: "phonejs" to develop a mobile project,
when I want to make a toolbar menusheet in empty views,

It seems menu text will show up twice in this demo: 
http://phonejs.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/Widgets/dxToolbar/Configuration?version=13_2#menuItemRender

I use it like this:

```
homeToolbarItems = [
    { location: 'menu', text: 'Logout',clickAction:logout },
    { location: 'center', text: 'Subscribe Manage' }
];
```

and the menu shows 'Logout'  twice, what can I do?​

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the menuItemRenderer is triggering twice. Once on initial view and once on click. I was able to remedy this buggy behavior by added a Initialize flag to the first view render. Then if the flag was tripped do not render the menu items again on additional request. Example...

```
    var menuInit = false;
    var viewModel = {
    menuItemRenderer: function(itemData, itemIndex, itemElement){
        if(menuInit == false){
            itemElement.dxButton({ text: "Execute \"" + itemData.text + "\" action" });
            menuInit = true;
        }
    }}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems it's a bug, I just asked the devExpress Phonejs develop team. And it have been solve several days ago.

Here is the question link: http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q571866